# Uploadify(3.1) with Magento(1.7)

Tags: php, magento, upload, uploadify

I am trying to implement uploadify in magento. My phtml template in magento has this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
$(function() {
    $('.uploadify').uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/index/upload') ?>',
        'auto'     : true,
    });
});
} ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

and the upload action like this:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
$targetFolder = '/uploadify/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
}
```

this is not working :(

the script inside the upload action is exactly the same as the script in uploadify.php, if i change the uploader option to uploadify.php it works ('uploader' : 'uploadify.php').

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it is isnt working is that you haven't supplied form_key which is need to verify that form was submitted from magento server itself.

Also you need to supply session id along with the url, else you will get login page as uploader wont necessarily use the same session as logged in user.

Therefore try the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
$(function() {
    $('.uploadify').uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'formData' : {'form_key' : '<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>'},
        'uploader' : '<?php echo Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/index/upload') ?>',
        'auto'     : true,
    });
});
} ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

Hope that helps?